# A simple and quite fun cipher: Revisited

Tags: cipher

---

### Background

---

On October 11th, 2023, I posted "[A simple and quite fun cipher puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122666/a-simple-and-quite-fun-cipher-puzzle)" as my first puzzle on Puzzling Stack Exchange, which was a puzzle where each decoding method was to be clued in the previous part (except for the first).

It is still unsolved to this day, so my (personal) goal for this puzzle is to create a puzzle that was themed similarly to my first puzzle that gives the originally intended answer.

Sorry if this ends up being a rotten puzzle like my first one.

---

Goal:

> - Uncover the final (secret) message

A perfect answer would include:

> - What each part is (decrypted)
> - What was used to decrypt each part
> - The final answer

---

Part 1

> Ryvi Myg, iye bokvvi nocsbo dy cyvfo drsc zejjvo? Govv, gri nyx'd iye qy *bofscsd* dro comyxn zkbd pyb xyg? Cebo, dro uoi dy nomyno sd scx'd okci dy nonemo vsuo wi Boneh zejjvo, led sd cdsvv cryevn lo okci dy psqebo yed.

Hint 2: (originally Hint 3)

> If anyone is struggling with decoding part 1, look at the last line of the "Background" section. (That's the Hint 1) If you're still having trouble, it's a rotation cipher that's used for decoding, but not ROT13.

Part 2

> +I@ KH:644 ?AH>7; A5DH 8E7J C:73 ><D ?H55I <H4B< I?B58>[ KHAGKKK p :7 :J:G2GK 7J@ HI @979 5=H:=] #A@A84KJ 8KK=:36AE 3K> 8G3@ IDK> ?DAEG GI>:> ;H 2I4;>>I><GC@BDE[ <K<43n

Hint 3:

> You might want to look back at my original cipher puzzle for help, since I had used this cipher originally. Then it's just a cipher with a key that you need to decrypt.

Hint 4:

> I'm also making a throwback to [my self referential cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123170/my-first-attempt-at-creating-a-self-referential-cipher?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C24.8249) if that helps.

Part 3

> "kiwk-iikiiiamqaw." Zij, byc nw vzrkgoyw fztzrl qv? Mg'l nuyfc! Lspafcj, xux niysp afix nw gvbuibwq kznek ys si qbnftugfqk mk M usa'm brpdp jtl amek'w thqnr gr hnkl nx. Rjgxz awd, me bfyqh si ckmteq mxu - tstp zj fhuemghj izh reeetx bo dgpgj dc kmiwg iczkdi! Lqc cty yeix bo og xz xjsqzv xuba ftfew urvy mj scxv a ywa Nwptymz xnuj, ayv me'x sexmteyeg dzfi. Zk tszvji, gh oee llp kzrfp rrfpmr, ezicj'j ssi dsex bhtfk jtl'pq lrzr mw dz...

Part 4

> xpjl rx rxl. xlz vfl rv. fah clsdxcm vuahg dm. ckz ynkogl - ivdiv - fw brov, qxcju hrv raqik onwybbl zjapv, erh arbbupf ixgu fiseqb. fc ai qqjmvdj, bzzkcys, qzgmae. byfox dme qp hvsb zcj wkor npibh rsofxcq vgc jbxcx kloxqhq, squ qxeo iftc ogoz mykyyv uhcyza wh czmri lhrgzvz. icw win!

Hint 5

> If the missing letters are making the decoded sentence have incorrect spelling/grammar, then which single letters would need to be added to make the spelling and grammar errors nonexistent?

---

---

Hint 6: (originally Hint 4) (originally Hint 2)

> The final answer (like my first puzzle) will be structured in the form `(WORD 1) (WORD 2), (WORD 3) (WORD 4)`

Hint 7:

> The first two words (which can be found in Part 1) were already [confirmed to be correct](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/122668/86115) originally, so your main goal is to find the other two.

Note:

> A spelling/capitalization mistake does not mean you decoded it incorrectly, nor does it mean that it was encoded incorrectly.

Comment: First, where's hint 1? And second, can I have another hint. I can't get past part 1 :D.

Comment: @LoganSweeney Hint one is hidden in the top, it'll help you get past part 1 (it's in the last line before part 1)

Comment: I'm not seeing it...

Comment: Oh... I already got the cipher but, I can't get to part two

Comment: I've put part two through so many decoders and nothing is coming up.

Comment: @LoganSweeney have you tried a rotation cipher to decode it partly?

Comment: Well, how do I know if the rotation is right if it's only partly?

Comment: @LoganSweeney In this case, the decoded text should have only letters. That's when you know that you need to use a "key" to decode the rest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152035/discussion-between-crsb0001-and-logan-sweeney).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOR PART 1:

> Put the message through **Rot16** and you get: *Holy Cow, you really desire to solve this puzzle? Well, why don't you go revisit the second part for now? Sure, the key to decode it isn't easy to deduce like my Redux puzzle, but it still should be easy to figure out.*

FOR PART 2:

> First, use **Rot47** and then, with the **vigenere cipher**, use the key **'REDUX'** to get: *It**t**reallys**h**eemslikey**a**ouwant**t**tosolvet**s**hispuzzle,howeverIamrunningoutofgoodideas.Althoughcertainlythenextpartwouldneverbeselfreferential,right?* **(All of the bold letters were added letters that shouldn't be there and they spell '***THATS***')**

FOR PART 3:

> Use the **vigenere cipher** again, but, use the key **'**SELF REFERENTIAL**'** to get:                                                                                        *"self-referential." Hey, why is everyone booing me? It's funny! Anyways, the final part is probably going to be diffi**c**cult if I don't t**r**ell you what's going on with it. After all, it would be pretty imp - cool if somebody did manage to solve my first puzzle! All you have to do to **s**solve this final part is open a new Cryptii tab**b**, and it's basically done. Of course, to get the final answer, there's one more thing you'll have to do…* **(Also notice the bold letters that shouldn't be there.)**

FOR PART 4:

> You literally just have to **open a new Cryptii tab** and it's on the cipher you need to use already. Make sure to **change it to decrypt and delete the plugboard**. Change the plugboard to the added letters from part 3 (**CR SB**) Don't forget to **put a space in between r and s**. When you do this you get:                   *Look at you. You did it. You finally solv**e**d it. Th**i**s puzzle - ciphe**r** - of mine, after fi**v**e whole gru**e**ling month**s**, has finally been solved. it is finally, finally, solved. Thank you to tho**s**e who have stuck through all three puzzles, and **I** hope that this cipher puzzle is still quality. And cut!* **(The bold letters are the letters that were missing from the message)**

THE FINAL ANSWER!:

> In the old version of this puzzle, it was confirmed that the first two words were **'HOLY COW'**. That's why in part one **the **C** in COW is capitalized**. The letters from part 2 spell **'THATS'**. The **'IMP'** from part 3 seems kind of outta place. And, **'IMP'** plus the missing letters from part 4 **(EIRVESSI)** spell **'IMPRESSIVE'**! **FINAL ANSWER:** ***HOLY COW THAT'S IMPRESSIVE!***

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This is the most fun I've had in a long time! I just wish I could make a puzzle this good. It was challenging but, not too hard (even though I asked for a lot of hints). And you were so nice to me about it. Some people tell me that I'm really talkative(because I am)but, you were so nice!!!! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. This is simply to detail my intended thought process that was supposed to be used when solving the puzzle. (as it took @LoganSweeney over 2 hours to solve and was solved using some methods I did not intend)

---

### Intended thought process

Part 1:

Decoded:

> **Holy Cow**, you really desire to solve this puzzle? Well, why don't you go *revisit* the second part for now? Sure, the key to decode it isn't easy to deduce like my Redux puzzle, but it still should be easy to figure out.

Intentional method:

> This was encoded using a ROT10 cipher, which was clued by "Sorry if this ends up being a ***rotten*** puzzle..." in the last line of the "Background" section. You can also solve this (as @LoganSweeney did) by encoding this using ROT16, although that is not intentional.

> We also get two words from here: Holy Cow, which we know from the original puzzle that those two words come first.

---

Part 2:

Decoded:

> It**t** really s**h**eems like y**a**ou want t**t**o solve t**s**his puzzle, however I am running out of good ideas. Although certainly the next part would never be self referential, right?

Note:

> The absence of a space between `self` and `referential` was sadly unintentional, and is the only mistake I made when making the puzzle.

Intentional method: (1/2)

> The method that I had intended was to revisit my original cipher puzzle and notice that I had actually used ROT47 to encode part of my original puzzle, and then notice that applying that to Part 2 returns text with all letters:
> Zxo zwiecc npwmfj pdsw gtfy rifb mks nwddx kwcqk xnqdgm, zwpvzzz A if iyivavz fyo wx ohfh dlwil. Rpopgczy gzzlibept bzm gvbo xszm nsptv vxmim jw axcjmmxmkvroqst, kzkcb?

Intentional method: (2/2)

> Then, this is recognizable as a Vigenere cipher, and use the key "REVISIT" (@LoganSweeney accidentally wrote "REDUX" as the key) to decode the rest of it:
> It**t** really s**h**eems like y**a**ou want t**t**o solve t**s**his puzzle, however I am running out of good ideas. Although certainly the next part would never be ***self referential***, right?

Note:

> Then you can notice that there are extraneous letters `t`, `h`, `a`, `t`, `s`, that now spell the third word.

---

Part 3:

Decoded:

> "self-referential." Hey, why is everyone booing me? It's funny! Anyways, the final part is probably going to be diffic***c***ult if I don't t***r***ell you what's going on with it. After all, it would be pretty ***imp*** - cool if somebody did manage to solve my first puzzle! All you have to do to s***s***olve this final part is open a new Cryptii tab***b***, and it's basically done. Of course, to get the final answer, there's one more thing you'll have to do...

Intentional method:

> As clued by Hint 4, this was supposed to be a throwback to my [attempt at making a self-referential cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123170/my-first-attempt-at-creating-a-self-referential-cipher?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C24.8249), which I made fun of by making the key "selfreferential". It was then supposed to be noticed by the solver that there are 4 extraneous letters (`c`, `r`, `s`, `b`) which comes in handy for part 4.

Note:

> I was originally intending for solvers to right away notice the `imp` in `imp - cool`, which was sort of a joke on my part (me about to accidentally "spoil" what the 4th word was), but it's okay if you didn't catch that right away.

---

Part 4

Decoded:

> look at you. you did it. you finally solvd it. ths puzzle - ciphe - of mine, after fie whole gruling month, has finally been solved. it is finally, finally, solved. thank you to thoe who have stuck through all three puzzles, and hope that this cipher puzzle is still quality. and cut!

With missing letters filled in: (@LoganSweeney accidentally included an extra `i` where I am pretty sure is still good grammar either way, although it did not stop them from getting the correct answer)

> look at you. you did it. you finally solv***e***d it. th***i***s puzzle - ciphe***r*** - of mine, after fi***v***e whole gru***e***ling month***s***, has finally been solved. it is finally, finally, solved. thank you to tho***s***e who have stuck through all three puzzles, and hope that this cipher puzzle is still quality. and cut!

Missing letters: (In order)

> `e` `i` `r` `v` `e` `s` `s`

Intentional method:

> Load up a new [Cryptii tab](https://cryptii.com/), and then remove the plugboard and put in `cr sb`, and make sure that it is decoding and not encoding.

Another place I messed up when creating the puzzle:

> I messed up really badly with this part because @LoganSweeney had not known what Cryptii was when I was assuming that everyone did (it is in the [Puzzling Tools](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/a-collection-of-puzzling-tools?rq=1), which is for some reason the first thing I looked for when I joined), so help was needed there.

---

What do we do now? Where's the fourth word?

What we do is

> Take `imp` from Part 3 and the missing letters from part 4. We have:
> `imp`, `e`, `i`, `r`, `v`, `e`, `s`, `s`

> I think my thought process was that if the person didn't catch `imp` from Part 3 originally, then Part 4's missing letters would have made them realize that it looked like they had to spell the word "impressive". Then they would go back to Part 3 and realize that there was an `imp` that would be able to finish the word.

Now

> We put `impeirvess` into an anagram solver (although it is solvable by hand, which is how I intended it to be) and get `impressive` as the fourth word.

---

So putting this all together, the answer is

> `HOLY COW, THAT'S IMPRESSIVE`

[<kbd>Chat transcript between me and Logan Sweeney if you want to see all of the hurdles both of us had to overcome for this puzzle to be solved</kbd>](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/152035)